# initiate a segue from another viewController

Tags: ios, xcode, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I'm trying to fire a segue from another viewController: So normally a segue is fired by tapping a Cell on a TVC. However the first time the App is initiated I need the user to setup some configuration.

I'm trying to fire this segue from the first viewController (also a TVC) the App displays. So I've created a public method on the SettingsTVC (where the segue is). The implementation of this method is as follows:

```
-(void)setStuff{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"setStuffFromSettings" sender:self];

}
```

On the first viewController I do as following on the click of a button:

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:4];

SettingsTVC *settings=[[SettingsTVC alloc]init];
[settings setStuff];
```

According to the NSLogs the methos is called correctly, but the App crashes telling me that:

```
'Receiver (<SettingsTVC: 0x812d730>) has no segue with identifier 'setStuffFromSettings''
```

Maybe I expect too much? I cannot set another segue because it would complicate things quite a lot and I don't want a viewController to be accessible from more than one place (I think Apple doesn't like it either).

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a segue with that ID connected to the VC that you are calling performSegue from.  See the image below.  That connection between your view controllers must be named correctly.

Check your connections and make sure the name matches.

[image: Segue Image]

Comment: Thanks, but I do have the segue correctly named and referenced to. That´s why I find myself puzzled by the error. Actually as a test I added a button on the viewController where the segue is originated and I added the  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"setStuffFromSettings" sender:self];
 code and it works. It doesn´t work when i try to initiate it from another viewControler via a public method.

Comment: It shouldn't matter which way you have it connected, but I always connect my Segue's to the VC and then call performSegue in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.  If you want any more help, you will need to zip up that project and email it to me or post a screenshot of your storyboard with the names of all the Segue's and also the code of the VC's you are having issues with.

Comment: I´ll try your suggestion as soon as I get home today. Thanks.